Given a positive definite matrix S, and a symmetric matrix A with small errors as S. How to prove that A is positive definite?
This is problem 4.14 in Multivariable Calculus with Applications by Peter D. Lax & Maria Shea Terrell.

A symmetric 2 by 2 matrix $A$ has been computed numerically with small errors as a symmetric matrix $S$, and each $i,j$ entry of $S$ is within $10^{-3}$ of the $i,j$ entry of $A$.
Let $S(u,v)$ be the quadratic function $U\cdot SU$ where $U=(u,v)$.
If for all $(u,v)$ it follows that $S(u,v) ≥ 3×10^{−2}(u^2 +v^2)$, show that $A$ is positive definite.

This problem looks simple. But I failed after tedious algebra. I will appreciate if any hint is given. Thank you so much.
What I tried is, let
$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\
b & c 
\end{bmatrix}
$,
$ S=
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e  \\
e & f 
\end{bmatrix}
$, $m=3×10^{−2}$.
Where $d=\lambda_1a,e=\lambda_2b,f=\lambda_3c$, and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in[1-10^{-3},1+10^{-3}] $
Then
$S(u,v) ≥ m(u^2 +v^2)$ for all $(u,v)$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$(d-m)u^2+2euv+(f-m)v^2>=0$ for all $(u,v)$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$d-m>0,f-m>0$, and $(d-m)(f-m)-e^2>=0$ $\Rightarrow$
$(\lambda_1a-m)(\lambda_3c-m)-\lambda_2^2b^2>=0$
Next I want to find an $n>0$ such that (I failed here)
$a-n>0,c-n>0$, and $(a-n)(c-n)-b^2>=0$
Then I can show that
$(a-n)u^2+2buv+(c-n)v^2>=0$ for all $(u,v)$
then finish the proof.

Include in a question what you have tried to solve a problem

Will add it after several hours, thank you for the reminder.

I think they mean that $|d-a| < 10^{-3}$, not $1-10^{-3} < d/a < 1+10^{-3}$.

Thank you @angryavian. I think your interpretation makes better sense. With the interpretation, the proof can be easily found in the book.

Hint:

Show that $|U \cdot SU - U \cdot AU| \le 10^{-3} (u^2 + 2uv + v^2)$.
What is the definition of "$A$ is positive definite"?


Thank you so much for the hint! From the hint I realized that maybe I misunderstood the meaning of "each i,j entry of S is within $10^{−3}$ of the i,j entry of A"? Does it mean $d-10^{-3}<=a<=d+10^{-3}$? where a,d are defined in the question description. My interpretation is different from this.  Would you please kindly comment on it? Thank you.

I left a comment above a few hours ago on this. Yes I think it means $|d-a| < 10^{-3}$. @JasonQian

Thank you @angryavian, and sorry that I cannot vote for your answer yet.
